# Android Studio unable to start and Enable Virtualization Tecnology

Tags: bios, intel-core-i7, emulator, android-studio

When I try to run the emulator for hello world, I get the error:

```
...\emulator.exe -avd Nexus_5_API_21_x86 -netspeed full -netdelay none
emulator: ERROR: x86 emulation currently requires hardware acceleration!
Please ensure Intel HAXM is properly installed and usable.
CPU acceleration status: HAX kernel module is not installed!
```

So, after reading a bit, I found out that I have to run intelhaxm.exe. Fine, so I went to Intel's website, downloaded it and it says that the processor is compatible, but I need to enable VT-x.

But I have already enabled it in BIOS, and am able to install Virtual Box and images (they require VT-x), checked that it is enabled in BIOS but the intelhaxm.exe still refuses to run.

My Win 8.1 is x64, but the emulator shows that it is x86. Is that a problem? If so, how do I change it in Android Studio?

What should I do now?

Comment: If Hyper-V is enabled, disable it. Also you don't necessarily have to use HAXM (which is faster), just change the option when creating the emulator to the other one (sorry I forgot what it's called haha). That way it won't matter whether you have VT-X or not. And the emulator should be x86.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

step 1: uninstall avast

step 2: install intelhaxm.exe

step 3: restart

step 4: re-install avast, update, quick scan and whatever.

step 5: run emulator on Intel CPU.